# How to run next batch file command in C#

Tags: c#, batch-file, batch-processing

I have two batch files,

The first, contains multiple commands, each command with two parameters, and it calls batch2
e.g.

```
C:\batch2 test1 "Hello this is a test"
C:\batch2 test2 "Hello this is a test as well"
```

The second, contains the .exe call, and takes in the parameters from batch1

```
C:\test.exe %1 %2
```

The .exe does the stuff, and the end of it is the following:

```
Console.WriteLine("complete", dir, output);
output.Close();
Console.Read();
```

The issue is, after the first line of batch1 is run, the second line is never run. What can I add to the end of the .exe (the C# program) to keep batch1 running for each subsequent line?

Or, how can I keep batch1 running after the first line?

Comment: You might want to look into threading and multi-threading.  This allows you to start two long processes and not have to wait for them to finish before starting the next exe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be a misunderstanding what a call is in batch vs C#.

Actually from your code you **don't call** batch2 but simply run it,
what doesn't leave an option to return to batch1. See `call /?` or visit http://ss64.com/nt/call.html

```
:: Batch1.cmd
@Echo off
Call "C:\batch2.cmd" test1 "Hello this is a test"
Call "C:\batch2.cmd" test2 "Hello this is a test as well"
```

---

```
:: Batch2.cmd
@Echo off
C:\test.exe %*
```

If you don't change any parameters in `Batch2.cmd` you can pass them all in one unchanged with `%*`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot *add* anything to the executable that would help you. It *waits*. Best case is you can *remove* the line that waits.

If you cannot, you can modify your batch file to just not wait for the executable to finish:

```
start C:\test.exe %1 %2
```

That makes your two executables run in parallel.

Or you could pipe a <kbd>Return</kbd> to your exe instead:

```
echo.|C:\test.exe %1 %2
```

Hacky, but it should work.

Comment: I understand, but I need the subsequent lines of batch 1 to run. Your solution makes the .exe return, but then it has only run the first line of batch1.

Comment: Did you try the start command? It should not wait for your exe to finish.